# SOLR ignores 'NOT' clause in query

Tags: solr

We have a simple domain where

```
FirstName_s:"Bob"
```

returns 40 documents, and

```
-Department_t:"Ninjas"
```

returns all of the documents (we don't have a ninja department).

We expected the query

```
(FirstName_s:"Bob") OR (-Department_t:"Ninjas")
```

to return all documents, however it only returned the original 40 documents.

We have experimented with a couple of different orderings, tried using 'NOT' instead of '-' all to no avail.

Is this expected behavior?
Perhaps more importantly, how do we get the behavior we expect?

Comment: Thanks to @jarosławgomułka, I've openned this [ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3315)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2209 so maybe parentheses are causing error. Does this work ?

```
FirstName_s:"Bob" OR -Department_t:"Ninjas"
```

Does rewritting the query in a way, that it won't contain OR (using [De_Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)) helping ?

```
-(-FirstName_s:"Bob" AND Department_t:"Ninjas")
```

Comment: Removing parens didn't work, but refactoring with De Morgans did. Thanks! I'll file a bug with Solr, I don't think we should have to use de Morgans on query generation.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an issue with multivalued fields and the way they behave with not.

We had to modify all of our not queries for multivalued fields to

```
(*:* -department_t:"Ninjas")
```